# Locking vertices

Tags: edit-mode, vertices

How can I lock vertices, so that they won't translate, even when selected by e.g. Proportional Editing? Ideally you should be able to lock all axes, or combinations X,Y or Z axis. The locked vertices should remain **visible**, so that certain vertices can be dragged to them, or they can be used as visual reference.

Comment: You may hide the vertices you don't want to be affected by the proportional editing. Select the desired vertices and press 'H'.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21577/is-it-possible-to-use-proportional-editing-without-affecting-or-hiding-nearby-ve , http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36146/is-there-a-way-to-do-proportional-editing-only-on-specific-vertices

Comment: Thanks, but by hiding the vertices it is impossible to see the effect of the editing on edges that are connected to these hidden vertices (and which have at the other end a vertex that IS allowed to move). There must be sum "lock" function in Blender ...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5533/599

Comment: I think the duplicate tag can be removed now

Comment: After all, you can select vertices you'd like to not being affected by whatever and separate them to another mesh. They will remain visible and accessible to snapping for example or visual guidance.